# Did the heat shield of the Vostok 1 capsule ablate during reentry?

Tags: spacecraft, reentry, heat-shield, vostok-program, ablator

This Wikipedia [article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wostok_(Raumschiff)) (in german) has some information about the heat shield of Vostok 1.

The heat shield was made from asbestos, its thickness was increased from 3 cm to up to 18 cm. The weight of the heat shield was 837 kg, the reentry module had 2.460 kg. [Vostok spacecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vostok_(spacecraft))

Did they use pure asbestos only, or a mix of asbestos fibers with a phenolic resin? If it was pure asbestos, did it ablate at all?

Answer (score 8):

> The heat protection material on the Vostok spacecraft is a resin-drenched asbestos fabric.
>   https://habr.com/ru/post/230445/
>   [image]
>
> Heat protection was mainly asbestos fabric, impregnated with bakelite resin. The maximum thickness of thermal protection in the frontal part was 110 mm, and the minimum - 40 mm in the rear.
>   http://epizodsspace.airbase.ru/bibl/k-r/1991/4-5vostok.html

[image]